Onde colocar a tag Script no HTML?
Estou com um código JS que realiza varias modificações em curto espaço de tempo de uma tag <canvas> e estou preocupado com a performance da chamada desse script!
Saberiam me informar se tem diferença de desempenho entre colocar a chamada no <head> ou no <body> neste contexto? ou se tem algum método para otimizar ainda mais a resposta do script sem a chamada padrão? Desde já, obrigado!
